# Theoretical origins of optical rotation

Tags: optics, physical-chemistry, polarization, quantum-chemistry

I'm not sure if I searched this with as fine-toothed a comb as I should have, but I found nothing online. I wanted to know if someone could point me to outlets wherefrom I could learn about the theoretical underpinnings behind phenomena such as [optical rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_rotation) of plane polarized light that result from the breakdown of chiral symmetry. To be specific, what exactly are the quantum-mechanical parameters that remain non-zero under chiral transformations and aggregate when integrated over a finite amount of matter to produce macroscopic effects like optical rotation?

Comment: What do you mean by optical rotation? Are you thinking of a specific experimental setup?

Comment: I would search for the quantum explanation of the faraday effect. The faraday effect is very well and simply described using Maxwell's eqs though